# Apply loop for chi square test in R

Tags: r, for-loop, chi-squared

Hi I am trying to calculate Chi Sq value for a set of data. Each set has 6 or 7 rows and they are grouped by a flag. I have totally 619 rows and 91 flags. So for each group I will get a chisq and p value. I want the output for all 91 sets so I can paste them in Excel. I am not much into coding but tried a loop which is ending up giving me only the last value of flag. It is saying that I have 50 or so warnings but not giving up the outputs as desired. Below is the snippet:

```
transaged <- transform(transaged, flag = as.numeric(interaction(HO_GROUP_CODE,START_DATE, drop=TRUE)))
for (i in 1:max(transaged$flag))
{
  survey=as.data.frame(rbind(transaged$CHO,transaged$HO))[transaged$flag==i]
  chisq.test(survey)
  Sys.time()
  chisq.test(survey)$p.value
  result <- cbind(rownames(transaged),chisq.test(survey)$p.value)
    }
```

I want the output to be something like
1. Chisq 21.34 pvalue 0.9
2. chisq 12.34 pvalue 0.89
and so on till 91

I also want the rownames to be combination of my first and second column from the data frame transaged since the flag was created by grouping them.

So it should be like:

```
HO_GROUP_CODE(1st entry),START_DATE(1st entry) Chisq 21.34 pvalue 0.9
HO_GROUP_CODE(1st entry),START_DATE(2nd entry) Chisq 21.34 pvalue 0.89

HO_GROUP_CODE  START_DATE  AGE  HO  HO*
1              12th Oct    4    12  23
1              15th Nov    5    23  34
2              16th Dec    6    23  35
.....
```

HO and HO* are in comparison for chi test while with varying ages grouped by on HO GROUP CODE and START DATE.

Please also suggest me if loop could be avoided. I found some help here but could not relate to what I need. If there is similar thread please redirect me to it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide a minimal dataset?

Comment: Sure. Updated the question. Please look at it.

Comment: If anyone is reading this. Thanks! I have got the issue solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the question I asked

```
i=1
for (i in 1:max(transaged$flag))

{
  survey=as.data.frame(rbind(transaged$CHO[transaged$flag==i],transaged$HO[transaged$flag==i]))
  chisq.test(survey)$p.value
  result1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(flag=i,ChiSq=chisq.test(survey)$statistic,DF=chisq.test(survey)$parameter,Pvalue=chisq.test(survey)$p.value))
result<-rbind(result,result1)
  }
finalage<-merge(result,unique(transaged[,.(HO_GROUP_CODE,START_DATE,flag)]),by='flag')
finalage$identifier<-'AGE'
```